# how to update array in couchbase using n1ql query

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchbase

```
{
"name":"nick",
"emailId":"nick123@gmail.com",
"subjects" : [{
   "name":"SOA",
   "tutor":"roshan",
   "classes" : "12"
 },
 {
   "name":"UNIX",
   "tutor":"mathew",
   "classes" : "9"
 }
],
"id" : "12345"
}
```

I want to add another set of subjects using update query.
i tired to put some query by seeing some website but it show error and i am unable to understand. 
It will be more helpful if you give suggestion and thanks for the help. 
the query which i tired was :-
[update `studapp`
ARRAY a.name= "networks", a.tutor= "shalin" ,a.classes=  "8" 
FOR a IN subjects END 
where id = '12345';]

Answer (score 5):

```
update `studapp`
SET subjects= ARRAY_APPEND( subjects, {   "name":"SE",
   "tutor":"Mani",
   "classes" : "7" } ) 
where id = '12345';
```

I got result as i needed (adding set of new values to the existing array)

**RESULT**

```
{
"name":"nick",
"emailId":"nick123@gmail.com",
"subjects" : [{
   "name":"SOA",
   "tutor":"roshan",
   "classes" : "12"
 },
 {
   "name":"UNIX",
   "tutor":"mathew",
   "classes" : "9"
 }
 {   
   "name":"SE",
   "tutor":"Mani",
   "classes" : "7"
 }
],
"id" : "12345"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See

[n1ql query to remove data from array which has parameter value null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181435/n1ql-query-to-remove-data-from-array-which-has-parameter-value-null)

https://dzone.com/articles/couchbase-n1ql-continuing-to-simplify-transition-f

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/update-value-in-an-array-of-strings-within-an-array/9797

[n1ql query to update multiple parameters in array of json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152577/n1ql-query-to-update-multiple-parameters-in-array-of-json-data)

[Update specific object in the array of object in couchbase 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331437/update-specific-object-in-the-array-of-object-in-couchbase-4-1)